# TypeScript how to convert an Array of objects to a concrete model?

Tags: typescript

I have this simple example below where I want to convert an array of objects to an array of Animal objects but I get this error `Type 'Animal[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise<Animal[]>': then, catch, [Symbol.toStringTag]` in the `Controller.getPersons()` function. I am not entirely sure what is causing this error.

```
class Animal {
  name: string;
  colour: string;

  constructor(name: string, colour: string) {
    this.name = name;
    this.colour = colour;
  }
}
```

The class where I have this function which promise to return an array of Animal objects `getPersons(): Promise<Animal[]>`

```
class Controller {
  data: { name: string; colour: string }[];

  constructor(data: { name: string; colour: string }[]) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  getPersons(): Promise<Animal[]> {
    const animals = this.data.map(a => new Animal(a.name, a.colour));
    console.log("animals -----> ", animals);
    console.log("type -----> ", typeof animals);
    return animals;
  }
```

This is my sample data which I want to convert to an array of Animal objects

```
const data = [
   { name: "Dog", colour: "Black" },
   { name: "Cat", colour: "White" }
];

const c = new Controller(data);
c.getPersons();
```

I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I believe your issue is you are returning `Animal[]` as opposed to `Promise<Animal[]>`.  Either alter the return type of `Promise<Animal[]>` to be `Animal[]` or update `data` to return a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `getPersons()` has a return type of `Promise<Animal[]>`. However what you're actually returning is just an array of animals.

As @ttugates points out in the comments, you have two options:

#### Change the return type

Change the return type of the method to `Animal[]` to match the implementation:

```js
getPersons(): Animal[] {
    // ...
}
```

#### Change the implementation

If you really need a promise, possibly to conform to a certain interface, create one and return it:

```js
getPersons(): Promise<Animal[]> {
    const animals = this.data.map(a => new Animal(a.name, a.colour));
    console.log("animals -----> ", animals);
    console.log("type -----> ", typeof animals);
    return Promise.resolve(animals);
}
```